# Unbalanced sample size: Bayesian vs. frequentist approach

Tags: bayesian, statistical-power

I have a question concerning tests between a large control cohort and a smaller number of cases in a simple comparison.
In particular I was wondering about the differences of baysian and frequentists approaches.
The question is partly inspired by [this recent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/108911/25843).

So lets say I have $n_a=10000$ and $n_b=10$ with $p$ variables and I suspect that difference between $n_b$ and $n_a$ is quite large.

As far as I know power, under the frequentist framework, is limited by the "strength" of the smallest sample size. So I would assume that, even with a relative large effect, I might be still unable to observe a significant p-value.

But what is the effect in a bayesian framework? How does my prior relate to sample size under this situation?