# Multivariate analysis?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, barplot, stacking

I realize this might be a fairly broad question but could anyone suggest an appropriate statistical approach for analyzing this kind of data? For example does % of dead cells differ significantly between doses and does the % of cell types differ?
[image]

Do the total % of dead cells and the types which make it up represent separate dependent variables and therefore constitute multivariate analysis?

Comment: Do you know the size of the sample from which this parblot was obtained?

Comment: Two replicates of 8000 cells for each dose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you want to test here is probably this: "are Dose and Type independent?"

#### $\chi^2$ Test of Independence

Since we know the sample size $N$ we can conduct a [$\chi^2$ test of independence](http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Chi-Squared_Test_of_Independence).

This is our observed fractions (per dose)

```
         dose
cell.type     0 0.1    1   10
        A 0.080 0.1 0.06 0.10
        B 0.135 0.2 0.22 0.15
        C 0.165 0.2 0.32 0.50
```

[image: boxplot]

Since there there are 8000 observations per dose, we get the following observed values

```
         dose
cell.type    0  0.1    1   10
        A  640  800  480  800
        B 1080 1600 1760 1200
        C 1320 1600 2560 4000
```

Assuming independence, we'd expect to get these values (it's row total times column total divided by overall total for each cell)

```
         dose
cell.type    0  0.1    1   10
        A  463  610  732  915
        B  961 1265 1517 1897
        C 1615 2126 2551 3188
```

So we compare them, calculate the $X^2$ statistics and calculate the $p$ value, which, in this case, is very low ($\approx 10^{-16}$).

Thus, we reject the independence hypothesis and conclude that they cannot be independent.

Caveat:

- the sample size is very big (8000) - which results in a too small $p$ value (see more [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108911/why-does-frequentist-hypothesis-testing-become-biased-towards-rejecting-the-null/))

#### R code

```
data_raw = c(0.080, 0.1, 0.06, 0.10,
             0.135, 0.2, 0.22, 0.15,
             0.165, 0.2 ,0.32, 0.50)

tbl = matrix(data=data_raw, nrow=3, ncol=4, byrow=T)
dimnames(tbl) = list(cell.type=c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                     dose=c('0', '0.1', '1', '10'))
barplot(apply(tbl, 2, rev), col=c('red', 'green', 'blue'), 
        ylim=c(0, 1), xlab='dose',
        legend.text=rev(c('A', 'B', 'C')))

N = 8000
observed = tbl * N
chisq.test(observed)
```

#### References

- http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Chi-Squared_Test_of_Independence

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would consider this a multivariate question.

To me it looks like logistic regression:

% dead cells ~ Dose * Type

The interaction term would tell you if the type of dead cells differs by dose.