# Recommended packages in R for obtaining confidence intervals adjusted by the false discovery rate

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons

In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72567990/correcting-confidence-intervals-for-multiple-comparisons-using-the-multcomp-pack/72644452?noredirect=1#comment128382644_72644452) I found out that one can perform a single type of familywise error correction of confidence intervals via the `multcomp` package in R.

In an answer on [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114879/should-we-address-multiple-comparisons-adjustments-when-using-confidence-interva?rq=1) the responder suggests that it is relatively simple to adjust confidence intervals for multiple comparisons using methods equivalent to the false discovery rate.

I was wondering if anyone knew of **any R packages that can adjust confidence intervals using the FDR method**, or indeed any other method other than the basic simultaneous familywise correction offered by the multcomp package?