# Is an F-test for equality of variance appropriate for a very large dataset?

Tags: variance, heteroscedasticity, large-data, f-test, levenes-test

I have a dataset with about 500,000 subjects and I am trying to establish whether the variance is equal. I first performed an F-test but then I realised the data is slightly skewed with kurtosis. So then I went with the  Brown-Forsythe variation of the Levene test of variance because it utilises the median and thus is less influenced by non-normality in the data. Then I realised that, due to the central limit theorem, if the sample is sufficiently large, then one can treat the data as normally distributed.

So now I am torn. Do I perform the F-test or the Levene's test? Or is there a better test to carry out on data this size?

Comment: Is it at all possible that the variances are exactly equal? With so much data, are both variants of the test significant? Why are you testing this in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes they both are significant. I am looking over the work of another person in order to check their methodology. She also ran effect size tests in order to get a better idea of actual treatment effects. So are you essentially saying that variance testing is redundant here?

Comment: It isn't clear what purpose is served, or if it matters (but then I can't tell for sure from the information given). How much did the variances differ? It may help to read these excellent CV threads: [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/), & [A principled method for choosing between t test or non-parametric e.g. Wilcoxon in small samples](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/121852/).

Comment: Thanks for the links and the reply. I agree that it all seems a bit redundant. All I can say is that, I am exploring this because running a t-test is what this person did originally and I am checking how good her methodology was. Clearly the answer here is not very but it is interesting none the less. Thanks for your input, much appreciated.

Comment: Running a t-test may well have been fine. Did she run the Welch version? How much did the variances differ?

Comment: According to her code, she did not run the Welch version and for the two datasets being compared in one instance, the var ratio was 1.072037

Comment: That variance ratio is so small I probably wouldn't bother running the Welch t-test either, & the results should be about identical both ways.

Comment: I suspect the thread on testing large datasets at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/are-large-data-sets-inappropriate-for-hypothesis-testing replies to the question that really ought to have been asked here.

Comment: See the question and my answer at [Why does frequentist hypothesis testing become biased towards rejecting the null?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108911/why-does-frequentist-hypothesis-testing-become-biased-towards-rejecting-the-null)

Comment: 1. "*I am trying to establish whether the variance is equal*" -- you can't establish equality. You can be pretty much certain the population variances are unequal. With a large enough n you'll reject equality, whether it actually matters or not. _ 2. "*due to the central limit theorem, if the sample is sufficiently large, then one can treat the data as normally distributed*" -- not so. If $n$ is very large, it may be that one can treat say the sample mean as normally distributed, but not the original data. If I have $10^9$ points from an exponential distribution, the distribution is still skew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A-priori, I find it highly implausible that the variances would be exactly equal (meaning that the null hypothesis should not be rejected, even with very high $n$ as you have here).  As a result, I do not see what purpose is served by testing for heteroscedasticity*.

Assuming one prefers to use a $t$-test (to, say, the Mann-Whitney $U$-test), when heteroscedasticity exists, using the [Welch correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test) may be appropriate.  However, given that the ratio of variances is $1.072037$, and $N = 500,\!000$, I can't see that it matters much either way.  I don't think the validity of the non-Welch-corrected $t$-test is threatened by heteroscedasticity so small, and I suspect the Welch $t$ would be virtually identical to the standard $t$ with that $N$.

<sub>* To understand this topic more thoroughly, it may help to read these two excellent CV threads:

  1. [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/)

  2. [A principled method for choosing between t test or non-parametric e.g. Wilcoxon in small samples.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/121852/)</sub>