# Trivial effect size BUT statistically significant?

Tags: effect-size

I am trying to compute effect size (SS predictor / SS total) is it possible to have a REALLY small effect size (0.02 no not 0.2 but 0.02) but have the effect be statistically significant?

Comment: Yes. Large sample size.

Comment: It might help the intuition to realize that in a complete census of a (finite) population, *any* nonzero effect size will be "significant".

Answer (score 9):

Yes. For any non-zero effect size as *n* approaches $\infty$, *p* approaches 0. This is because for Wald type tests, the test statistic is $\frac{\theta}{s_{\theta}}$, and $s_{\theta}$ typically looks something like $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $s$ is a standard deviation (e.g., of one's data for the *t* test).

[Further elaboration on significance and tiny effect sizes from the perspective of *equivalence* and *relevance*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108911/why-does-frequentist-hypothesis-testing-become-biased-towards-rejecting-the-null/108914#108914).