Does the risk of incorrectly rejecting the null hypothesis increase with a large sample?
I've seen something like this a lot: "a small effect size can lead to significant results if the sample size is large enough". I can't understand this clearly.
To me it sounds something like this: increase the sample size and you will eventually definitely reject the null hypothesis (that is, you will 100% definitely reject the 0 hypothesis if you make the sample size large up to a certain size).
Reread this thread. As far as I understood, given my modest experience in statistics, that null hypothesis is correctly rejected.
Decided to check this in the code for the ttest_1samp test, making popmean=15.03 with a very small difference from the sample (mean=15). The slider selects N - the sample and the distribution is redrawn in real time, the vertical bars are the upper limit values ​​(blue) and p_value (orange).
Update 08.11.2024
Since the average of the array is different from the declared one, for accuracy I made the value mu_0 = mu_1 + value by adding some value to it. mu_0 is drawn on the graph in green, the confidence interval is magenta. The graph also displays the p-values ​​themselves, the average values, and the interval(CI). Change N and the graph is redrawn dynamically. Now I have also checked with a large difference in the means, the sample size is needed to reject even smaller. The difference can be set via value.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import t, norm, ttest_1samp
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

ax_n = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
s_n = Slider(ax_n, "N", valmin=7, valmax=30000,valinit=21, valstep=1)

value = 0.03

def update(val):
    N = s_n.val
    rvs = np.sort(norm.rvs(loc=15, scale=1, size=N, random_state=1))
    mu, std = np.mean(rvs), np.std(rvs)
    mu_0 = mu + value
    z_values = (rvs - mu) / std
    df = N - 1
    pdf = t.pdf(rvs, loc=mu, scale=std, df=df)
    tst = ttest_1samp(rvs, popmean=mu_0)
    l, r = t.ppf(1 - 0.975, df=df), t.ppf(0.975, df=df)
    ci = tst.confidence_interval(confidence_level=0.95)
    ci_0, ci_1 = np.round(ci, 4)
    ci = (ci - mu) / std
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(z_values, pdf, lw=2, color="red")
    ax.axvline(x=(mu_0 - mu) / std, color="green", label="mean 0")# average of 0 hypothesis
    ax.axvline(x=ci[0], linestyle="--", color="magenta", label="CI")
    ax.axvline(x=ci[1], linestyle="--", color="magenta")
    ax.axvline(x=l, linestyle="--", color="blue", label="alfa")# alfa
    ax.axvline(x=r, linestyle="--", color="blue")# alfa
    ax.axvline(x=t.ppf(tst[1]/2, df=df), linestyle="--", color="orange", label="p-value")#p-value
    ax.axvline(x=-t.ppf(tst[1]/2, df=df), linestyle="--", color="orange")#p-value
    ax.text(0, (np.max(pdf) + np.min(pdf))/2, "p_value =" + str(round(tst[1], 4))
            + "\n" + "mu_0 =" + str(round(mu_0, 5)) + "\n" + "mu_1 =" + str(round(mu, 5)) +
            "\n" + "ci_0 =" + str(ci_0) + "\n" + "ci_1 =" + str(ci_1), fontsize=12)
    ax.legend()

s_n.on_changed(update)
update(0)

plt.show()



Welcome to Cross Validated! When you set 15.03, you have made it so the null hypothesis is incorrect and the alternative is correct. Then the test tends to reject the null in favor of the alternative. What’s the problem?

No, the risk is the same, that's what alpha does. With larger samples you will reject the null more quickly because you are more sure in the result. Whether that difference is meaningful is a debate of statistical vs practical significance.

@Dave the problem is that when generating rvs values, for example with size N - 30, the hypothesis 0 is not rejected, but with N - 4000 it is rejected. Everything is the same average and standard deviation, there are just more values. What has changed in the values ​​themselves? Of course, I understand that with a larger N, the confidence interval has become narrower and there is a higher probability that the general average will not fall into it.

@user2974951 I don't need comparisons of such small differences in means. I just gave it as an example. Is it correct to use an effect size of 0.8 to understand whether a test should be conducted? And again, if you greatly increase the sample size, the 0 hypothesis will still be rejected.

See the top question under "Related" in the sidebar:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108911/why-does-frequentist-hypothesis-testing-become-biased-towards-rejecting-the-null
And the illustration in the answer here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66473/in-what-settings-would-confidence-intervals-not-get-better-as-sample-size-increa/66475#66475
Also relevant:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/566065/how-can-i-reduce-a-very-large-sample-size-for-statistical-significance-sampling
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125750/sample-size-too-large

There are a number of other posts on site that are relevant as well; see the sidebars of these links, and pointers in answers and comments, and consider some searches using relevant keywords from these various threads.

I updated my code. Added confidence interval (pink vertical stripe) and mean (green vertical stripe). When mean is not in interval p-value < 0.05. Is it possible to find the alpha boundaries based on 0 mean, for z_values? I want to count the % of elements that are outside these boundaries. As is usually done when comparing two normal distributions. Although probably in this case it is not done this way, after all, the averages are compared and not the values ​​themselves.?

The probability of rejecting the null when it is true is the Type I error rate or alpha, which is typically set to 0.05. This is not affect by the sample size. Sample size can indirectly affect your probability of rejecting the null (since you're more likely to identify real effects and reject the null with more data), but it doesn't affect the probability of making a Type I error. If the null really is true, you should expect to incorrectly reject it 5% of the time no matter how many samples you have.
What does change with sample size is the power to detect an effect of a particular magnitude - the probability that if an effect of some magnitude really exists, that you will correctly reject the null. With 100 samples you might reliably deem an effect of moderate to large magnitude to be significant, but with 100,000 samples, you might reliably deem a very small effect to be statistically significant. Your example shows that with increasing sample size, you have additional power to correctly reject the null hypothesis that the means are equal when they are not (15 is not equal to 15.03). With a huge amount of data, you'll very often reject the null hypothesis because you have high power to detect very small effects. That doesn't make the test "wrong", but it may be in the realm of "not meaningful" to say there's a statistically significant difference of some practically meaningless magnitude.
In short, as sample size goes up, the power goes up and the likelihood of incorrectly accepting the null (a Type II error) goes down. The probability of incorrectly rejecting the null if it is true (Type I error) doesn't change, but the probability of correctly rejecting the null if it is false does go up - you'll generally be more likely to reject a false null with higher sample size.

"...doesn't affect the probability of being wrong when you do [reject the null]" looks confusing, because there isn't any part of hypothesis testing that enables one to evaluate this conditional probability.  Because the rest of this post looks accurate, I wonder whether you meant something other than what you wrote in this passage.

@whuber Good point, the Type I error rate is what remains unchanged, but that represents the chance of being wrong given that the null is correct, not the chance of being wrong given that we reject the null. Edited, but now I wonder if it is possible to evaluate what I wrote. If I flip one coin 10 times, and another one 1000 times, and deem both significantly biased, is the latter more likely correct? The probability of a false positive is 5% with both if they're not biased, and if they are biased, the test with higher N should detect it over a larger range of effect sizes.

@whuber In other words, can we infer that rather than having no effect as I wrote, higher sample size decreases the probability of being wrong when rejecting the null?

You seem to have some prior distribution in mind where you write "more likely correct."

@NuclearHoagie if you apply Bayes theorem, it can be shown your posterior P(Biased∣Reject) follows a monotonic increasing hyperbola in the first quadrant with any assumed prior P(Biased), and as test sample size increases with its power, the likelihood P(Reject∣Biased) increases, so your posterior also increases as sample size increases.

@NuclearHoagie "a small effect is statistically significant" with a large sample size. If the difference in means is made larger, then an even smaller sample size is needed to obtain a p-value less than 0.05, in my case (updated the code, the difference can be set in the value variable for one-sample t-test). And then I wonder, is p-value really that useful when the sample size is large?

@inquirer With very large N, a hypothesis test where the null hypothesis is exactly zero effect size may not be terribly useful, as you'll declare even miniscule effects significant. It can be useful to filter results by both significance and effect size, or to define the null so that you're testing not for some arbitrarily small but non-zero effect, but for some practically meaningful effect size. I'd agree p-value can be somewhat less useful on its own with very large N, or at least that it doesn't tell the whole story.
